# How to find out who called me

Tags: python

When using an IDE like PyCharm python is being called via pydevd.py (is parent?).
On command prompt like cmd.exe scripts can use the prompt color sequences e.g. "\033[0m".
Well, withing PyCharm it looks strange when using those.
The question is: if you can find out who called the script, if running on cmd line or not to be able to use those sequences properly.

Comment: Could you include the code and what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean witch python interpreter called it? You can set it in Pycharm(and other IDEs) and often the ones running in command prompt are differently set in IDE.Would suggest getting it straight and choosing the right one in Interpreter settings.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but I believe it may answer the problem you're trying to solve.

I've had success using the colorama package in the past, which handles the details of how to set colours for you in a cross-platform way. This also appears to work correctly within PyCharm.

For example:

```
from colorama import init, Fore

init(autoreset=True)
print(Fore.RED + 'Hello world, but in red')
```